# adding values in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

```
int n, total, array[4] = {5,4,2,7}

for (n =0; n<4; n++)
{
total = array[n] + array[n+1];
}
```

5+4=9+2=11+7=18

I know that I need to store the value of the sum into a variable but how do I make the variable loop back to be added to the next number in the array.

Answer (score 5):

```
int n, total = 0, array[4] = {5,4,2,7}

for (n =0; n<4; n++)
{
  total += array[n];
}
```

Comment: ah forgot about the compound assignment

Comment: @thao nguyen: the compund assignment is nothing special here, you could also write it `total = total + array[n]`. The `total` on the left is the value of the variable before the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do the array+1 position adding. Only have to accum the values in one variable

```
// Declaration of total variable and values array
int total=0, array[4]={5,4,2,7}

// For loop
for (int n=0; n<4; n++) {
    // Total accum
    total+=array[n];
    // Use += or you can use too this: total=total+array[n];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets

`total = array[0] + array[1]` -> 9

then

`total = array[1] + array[2]` -> 6

then

`total = array[2] + array[3]` -> 9

then

`total = array[3] + array[4]` -> undefined behavior

which of course not what you want. You ask

> I know that I need to store the value
>   of the sum into a variable but how do
>   I make the variable loop back to be
>   added to the next number in the array.

Well, the variable is `total`, and you want to add it to the next number in the array; that's simply

```
total = total + array[n]
```

(or `total += array[n]`).

All that remains is to initialize `total = 0` so that the first add (`total = total + array[0]`) sets `total` to `array[0]` rather than some undefined value.